# Send message to specific channel in Discord with JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

How to ask the bot to send a message to another channel (specific channel) that is not the same as the bot receive command?

Let's say bot receives the message `!ban @xxx` in channel `#a` and if action is completed, bot sends `ban to user @xxx is given` to channel `#b`.

code `Main.java`:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.*;

public class Main {

    private static String token = "NDk0MjI2Mjk2OTY5MjMyMzk0.DowgCA.j0sQHnBV3wm70rzz7Q78rX0NVPU";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        try {
            JDA api = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken(token).build();
            api.addEventListener(new MyEventListner() );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

code `MyEventListner.java`:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Member;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.MessageChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Role;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.User;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        if (event.getAuthor().isBot()) return;

            User author = event.getAuthor();
            Message message = event.getMessage();
            String content = message.getContentRaw();
            MessageChannel channel = event.getChannel();
            Member member = event.getMember();
            String nickname = member.getNickname();
            Role role = event.getGuild().getPublicRole();
            //that is the most needed part, I believe
}
```

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: @AlexCouch JDA. It's mentioned in the title)

Comment: Sorry I was on mobile I must've completely missed it trying to read the message or something. What code do you have currently?

Comment: @AlexCouch few sec

Comment: Basically, the added code have to be in "MyEventListner". What is needed : send message to specific channel (not same where bot received command)

Comment: You should be able to just get all the channels in a guild from the current guild object provided to you by the event. I don't have any project that I can look through, just documentation and examples on the official JDA github repo. Btw, you need to show your code in your post, not as an external link.

Comment: @AlexCouch that is a thing... I cannot find how to browse all channels.

Comment: @AlexCouch code added properly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is simple:

```
TextChannel textChannel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelsByName("CHANNEL_NAME",true).get(0);
textChannel.sendMessage("MESSAGE").queue();
```