# JDA - send message

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I have my own Discord BOT based on JDA. I need to send a text message to the specific channel. I know how to send the message as onEvent response, but in my situation I do not have such event.

I have: Author (BOT), Token and Channel number.

**My question is: how to send the message to this channel *without an event*?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send message to specific channel in Discord with JDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508107/send-message-to-specific-channel-in-discord-with-jda)

Comment: Not duplicated! I know what you mean and I clearly described, that I do not have event. Solution which you sent me is related onEvent. I want send direct message to the channel - anytime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I think I know what you mean. You don't need to have an event to get an ID of a channel and send a message. The only thing you need to do is to instantiate the JDA, call awaitReady(), from the instance you can get all channels (MessageChannels, TextChannels, VoiceChannels, either by calling

- get[Text]Channels()
- get[Text]ChannelById(id=..)
- get[Text]ChannelsByName(name, ignore case))

So 1. Instantiate JDA

```
    JDABuilder builder; 
    JDA jda = builder.build();
    jda.awaitReady();
```

2. Get Channel

   ```
   List<TextChannel> channels = jda.getTextChannelsByName("general", true);
   for(TextChannel ch : channels)
   {
       sendMessage(ch, "message");
   }
   ```
3. Send message

   ```
   static void sendMessage(TextChannel ch, String msg) 
   {
       ch.sendMessage(msg).queue();
   }
   ```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need only one thing to make this happen, that is an instance of `JDA`. This can be retrieved from most entities like User/Guild/Channel and every Event instance. With that you can use `JDA.getTextChannelById` to retrieve the `TextChannel` instance for sending your message.

```java
class MyClass {
    private final JDA api;
    private final long channelId;
    private final String content;

    public MyClass(JDA api) {
        this.api = api;
    }

    public void doThing() {
         TextChannel channel = api.getTextChannelById(this.channelId);
         if (channel != null) {
             channel.sendMessage(this.content).queue();
         }
    }
}
```

If you don't have a JDA instance you would have to manually do an HTTP request to send the message, for this lookup the [discord documentation](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message) or [jda source code](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA). The JDA source code might be a little too complicated to take as an example as its more abstract to allow using any endpoint.