# How to make a time based announcement bot

Tags: java, maven, discord-jda

I'd like to make a bot that simply says something in a set channel at a set time 2 days a week, but I'm not sure how to do this, I'm very new to this so please be gentle

I tried setting a while loop to check the time constantly and if it matches a certain time it could say the announcement but the API seems to insist that regardless of there being another possible variable like my time variables there HAS to be a discord event for it to do anything.

Please help!

This is my "mondayevent.java" class that I've sort of given up on.

```
package events;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.TextChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.ReadyEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class mondayevent extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onReadyEvent(ReadyEvent event) {
        while(true) {
            DayOfWeek dow = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek();
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
            if(dow.equals("sunday") || dow.equals("Sunday")){
                onGuildReady();
            }
        }
    }
}


//Announce "Hey! Just a reminder that there's a Business team meeting today directly following school in the STEM Lab! @Business Team "

//TC:meeting-announcements(50905546**rest of ID**)
```

This is my "time.java" class that I've sort of tried to implement into the monday event class

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class time {
    public DayOfWeek dow = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek();
    public DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    public LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

And this is my bot main class:

```
import events.mondayevent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;

public class botmain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JDA jda = new JDABuilder("***token here***").build();
        jda.addEventListener(new mondayevent());
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I see is that I want this to repeat at a certain time every week say like 6pm on a Sunday and repeat weekly, not just one time, and I’m wondering how to implement time into this with the time setup that I have. 

Moreover, how can I go about checking to see if the time is correct then just send a message without having to wait for another server event like having received a message

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`docu`](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/7%29-Using-RestAction#using-completeafter-submitafter-and-queueafter). Depending on whether your event needs to be cancelable you should go with submitAfter. As for the starting point of your scheduling: you should receive a JDA Event when your bot connects.

---

For sending a message without an event check [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484588/jda-send-message/53507080#53507080) or this [`link`](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/issues/787) (copied example below):

> *Given a JDA instance ..*

```java
JDA jda = ...

jda.getTextChannelById(...)
jda.getPrivateChannelById(...)
jda.getUserById(...).openPrivateChannel().queue(channel -> ...)
jda.getGuildById(...).getTextChannelById(...)
jda.getGuildById(...).getTextChannels()
jda.getGuildById(...).getMemberById(...).getUser().openPrivateChannel().queue(channel -> ...)

//For Clients
jda.asClient().getGroupById(...)
jda.asClient().getFriendById(...).getUser().openPrivateChannel().queue(channel -> ...)
```

---

> The problem I see is that I want this to repeat at a certain time every week say like 6pm on a Sunday and repeat weekly, not just one time, and I’m wondering how to implement time into this with the time setup that I have.

If you don't want to use `jda` for the scheduling you can always do it on your own using a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). You might want to read this [`tutorial`](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-scheduledexecutorservice-examples/).

---

> Moreover, how can I go about checking to see if the time is correct

You're bot is running somewhere so you either have to trust the local time or access some kind of `ntp server` to get the time from there.