# Java&JDA - Send message without any event

Tags: java, discord-jda

So, i have problem. I'm making script on Java with sending logs to my discord server. And i using JDA Api. That script should send message when it will be opened. So without any events. Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Some edit: Sorry for my bad english, ima from Russia btw

Comment: Any code to post it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDA - send message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484588/jda-send-message)

Comment: @Minn huh? So, i just don't know how to set channel for send message. I just know, how to set it when event is happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first get the bot instance you are working with, then get the text channel. After you made sure the bot can talk there, you can send a message (or multiple).

It would look something like this:

```java
TextChannel textChannel = YourBotInstance.getJda().getTextChannelById("386242731875368960");
if(textChannel.canTalk()) {
    textChannel.sendMessage("Your message here.").queue();
}
```