# How can a discord bot exchange data over multiple servers?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

For example if I add my bot to server 1 and server 2, how can I do something on server 2 when a certain event happens on server 1? Is that even possible?

I don't have any code yet, I just wanna know if this is even possible with the Discord Java API (JDA).

Comment: Yes its possible, but without knowing which library you use we can't help you.

Comment: As I stated in my post, I use JDA (Java Discord API)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDA - send message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484588/jda-send-message)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

1. When you start your bot with JDA, you'll get a `JDA` object, let's call it jda (`public JDA jda`).
2. Next you map the events with a ListenerAdapter. In the ListenerAdapter, you'll specify what you want to do when each event is received. Check what events you can listen to in the Method Summary section at https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/hooks/ListenerAdapter.html. You just need to override the methods you want.
3. In your implementation, let's say `@Override (...)onEmoteAdded() {(your code goes here)}`, you can have a piece of code that manipulates another server such as `jda.getGuildById​(id).queue()`