# JDA - Send message to specific channel

Tags: discord-jda

I am currently making a bot for discord using Java and jda. I want to let the bot send a message to a specific channel. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is already asked in the StackOverFlow community.

if you search it in StackOverFlow, you find [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508107/send-message-to-specific-channel-in-discord-with-jda)

And here is the simple answer! ;)

```js
TextChannel textChannel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelsByName("CHANNEL_NAME",true).get(0);
textChannel.sendMessage("MESSAGE").queue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a channel by ID like so:

```java
TextChannel txtChannel = event.getJDA().getTextChannelById("348110542667251712");

if (txtChannel.canTalk()) {
    txtChannel.sendMessage("Your message here.").queue();
}
```

With the `.canTalk()` method you can verify, the bot has permission to read and send messages in that channel.