# What is the ".get(0)" in this piece of code?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I do not understand what i should do with .get(0).

What I am just trying to do is declare a channel and message to it.

I got a solution and it seems perfect for my use case, but it does not explain in depth what the code does. The only thing I don't understand is what .get(0) is or what it does.

This is the solution I found for my use case: [Send message to specific channel in Discord with JDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508107/send-message-to-specific-channel-in-discord-with-jda)

Here is my code so far:

```
TextChannel channel1 = event.getGuild().getTextChannelsByName(eventChannel,true).get(0);
channel1.sendMessage("The event-channel has been set to this channel.").queue();
```

I am hoping that someone can explain more about the .get(0) part and what I should set the value to. That is where the run failure is happening. (I haven't set the value to anything yet because I don't know what to do with it or set it to)

Comment: you should look at what `getTextChannelsByName()` is returning probably a list if thats the case get(0) will return item at 0 index.

Comment: "That is where the run failure is happening." - If you get an error you should ask about it here and post details on the error. You also seem to be very new to Java or you'd not be puzzled by the `get(0)`. Try to work on the basics before diving into more complex things. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches that way.

Comment: @Thomas i am sorry if i made my question seem like i was very new to java. I made some simple java projects and have been learning about 1 year now. I worked out most of the basics but skipped some because they didnt seem necessary. That is why i dont understand what .get(0) is used for.

Comment: Well, that should be a hint that skipping basics isn't the best option. You should also work on skills such as decomposing a call chain, analyzing the return values, reading javadocs and using a debugger. You will very likely have many situations where you don't understand a piece of code immediately and being able to analyze it yourself (at least to some extent) is a good skill to have. That way you should be able to see what `getTextChannelsByName(eventChannel,true)` returns and then look up what the `get(int)` method on the returned element does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get(0)` is the same as the things before it (`.getGuild()`, `getTextChannelsByName(…)`): a method call.

`event.getGuild()` gives you an object which, besides others, provides access to text channels. `.getTextChannelsByName(…)` gives you a list of text channels identified by the given name.

As you only want one channel, and you maybe even expect to get exactly one channel, you get element #0 of this list, and this is done with `.get(0)` on the list.